# remove all punctuation except hyphen & underscore of a string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to remove all punctuation from beginning and end of a string except hyphen,underscore.

Example:if input is `spice-b32.` Or `lg_b32;` Then string after using preg_replace(); should be: `spice-b32` and `lg_b32`;

i'm also tried to use `preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]/',$inm)` for data validation use  `$inm=preg_replace('/^\PL+|\PL\z/','',$inm);` but, when input `a!-read_` result is `a!-read`

but output should be: `a-read`

if this preg_replace() OR preg_match() is not correct,then plz help..

Comment: (extra feature: remove mentioned punctuation if it is in beginning and end of a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, then something like this will do for you:

```
$inm=preg_replace('/[,.!?]*([-_]+)[,.!?]*/',
                  '\1',
                  preg_replace('/\b[.,?!]+|[.,!?]+\b/', '', $inm);
```

Feel free to add other characters that need to be stripped off to the character groups.

Comment: sorry,nothing special happen,is there any Wild-Card type of features in preg_match() OR preg_replace() which allow us to work with limited special char. i'm student so...

Comment: @pal I'm not sure I understand your comment. I did test this with your sample inputs.

Comment: if input='s@p_st-b!4';  then Output is 's@p_st-b4' ; i want output like: 'sp_st-b4';

Comment: @pal Then add the `@` to the character groups in all places.  As I stated, add other characters you need to strip to the groups.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$arr = array('spice-b32.', 'lg_b32;', 'a!-read_');
foreach ($arr as $str) {
    echo preg_replace('/^[^\P{P}_-]+|[^\P{P}_-]+$/u', '', $str),"\n";
}
```

This will remove all punctuation (except `_` and `-`) from the begining or end of a string.

**output:**

```
spice-b32
lg_b32
a!-read_
```

Comment: thanks...can you make this output more effective Like: [ a-read ] not [ a!-read_ ].

Comment: suppose i have a table contain 'item','model' column. Now item='camera' & model='wsc-184'; if anyone give input like model='wsc!-184_' then  it will accepted for this programing Fault; i want to create this format (like: model='wsc-184'). what should i do?

Comment: @pal: Sorry, I don't get you. You said in the question that you want to remove all punctuation except `_` and `-` at th ebeginig or at the end of the string, but now youwant to remove `!` in the middle and `_` at the end. Could you clarify what you really want with some inputs and expected result in your question?

Comment: yes title was incorrect..but in body, where i explain my actual question those are correct.

Comment: just read question: "...but, when input a!-read_ result is a!-read
but output should be: a-read ";